# Google Map API use LatLng or Address

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Javascript to render an embedded Google Map canvas on my website.

The inputs to the rendering are lat/lng coordinates that are retrieved from a database. However, if lat/lng returns null, the map will render based on the corresponding address string retrieved from the database. The following script always renders correctly for lat/lng coordinates inputs, but doesn't work for address input. Strangely, when I refresh the page multiple times, the address input would work randomly. I'm trying to cut out this randomness. Think I'm pretty close but I can't seem to find the missing link.

Note: if lat/lng is null, a default value is applied to $lat and $lng so it doesn't mess up the JS below.

I would appreciate if anyone could tell me what's wrong with the below code that's causing the random rendering of address strings.

```js
var map;
var marker;
var geocoder;

function initialize() {
  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
  var estLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng( <? php echo $lat; ?> , <? php echo $lng; ?> );

  var mapOptions = {
    center: estLatLng,
    zoom: 17,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    disableDefaultUI: false,
    streetViewControl: true,
    scrollwheel: false
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: estLatLng,
    map: map,
    draggable: false,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    title: "<?php echo $name;?>"
  });
}

function toggleBounce() {
  if (marker.getAnimation() != null) {
    marker.setAnimation(null);
  } else {
    marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

<? php
} ?>
$(".navbar").load("navbar.html", function() {
  $("#navbarrestaurants").addClass("active");
});

$(document).ready(function() { <? php
  if ($calcAddress) { ?> // this chunk of code is not loaded if lat/lng is not null
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({
      'address': "<?php echo $address;?>",
      'componentRestrictions': {
        country: 'Singapore'
      }
    }, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
      } else {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
      }
    }); <? php
  } ?>
});
```

Comment: What does the code look like that the browser sees under these conditions?  Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Are you getting a 'map is undefined' error in your browser? I think that your code in 'document ready' is being executed before that in 'window load' (which is where map is defined).

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that the code in $(document).ready is being executed before that in your initialize function (listening for window load). The load event is called once the page is completely loaded, including images, etc, while everything in your document ready block is called slightly earlier when the DOM is ready.

Because it is executed sooner, and acting upon variables like map, that haven't been set up yet by the initialize function, the code in your geocoding callback is probably causing errors when it tries to alter the map center and set marker coords.

Try executing your geocoding code after the map is initialized. ie: wrap it in its own function and call it at the end of the initialization function.

```
function initialize() {
  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
  var estLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng( <? php echo $lat; ?> , <? php echo $lng; ?> );

  var mapOptions = {
    center: estLatLng,
    zoom: 17,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    disableDefaultUI: false,
    streetViewControl: true,
    scrollwheel: false
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: estLatLng,
    map: map,
    draggable: false,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    title: "<?php echo $name;?>"
  });

  codeAddress();
}
```

ex: http://jsfiddle.net/j7pb7w3d/2/

This isn't great however, as the map starts with its default center, then visibly jerks a second later to the new address.

Instead you could determine whether or not geocoding is necessary first, and do this before the map is loaded, then use the result to set the map center and marker when the map is first created. Ex: http://jsfiddle.net/qsefxu5q/2/

Note these examples are hardly perfect and will need to be changed for your purposes. Hopefully they give you some ideas.